# duplicate source list entry

Tags: apt, updates

After installing google chrome beta version, when i used (`sudo apt-get update`) this command, gives me below prompt.

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

Answer (score 0):

You can comment out the entry in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list with sed:

```
    sed -i '3 s/^/#/' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
```

This places a hashtag in front of the third line of the google-chrome.list file, like this:

```
    # deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```